Using high speed usb mode with zynqmp
I am trying to use usb on my custom board with zynqmp and usb3310 phy.
The usb full speed works great but when I insert an high speed device (like usb storage) the kernel seems to not switch to high speed.
My dtsi file :
usb1: usb@ff9e0000 {
    #address-cells = <2>;
    #size-cells = <2>;
    status = "disabled";
    compatible = "xlnx,zynqmp-dwc3";
    reg = <0x0 0xff9e0000 0x0 0x100>;
    clock-names = "bus_clk", "ref_clk";         
        power-domains = <&zynqmp_firmware PD_USB_1>;
    resets = <&zynqmp_reset ZYNQMP_RESET_USB1_CORERESET>,
         <&zynqmp_reset ZYNQMP_RESET_USB1_HIBERRESET>,
         <&zynqmp_reset ZYNQMP_RESET_USB1_APB>;
    reset-names = "usb_crst", "usb_hibrst", "usb_apbrst";
    ranges;
        phy_type = "ulpi";
        usb-phy = <&usb_phy1>;
    
        dwc3_1: usb@fe300000 {
        compatible = "snps,dwc3";
        reg = <0x0 0xfe300000 0x0 0x40000>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        interrupt-names = "host", "peripheral", "otg";
                //interrupt-names = "dwc_usb3", "otg", "hiber";
        interrupts = <GIC_SPI 70 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>,
                 <GIC_SPI 70 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>,
                 <GIC_SPI 74 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
        clock-names = "bus_early", "ref";
        iommus = <&smmu 0x861>;
        snps,quirk-frame-length-adjustment = <0x20>;
        snps,resume-hs-terminations;
        
        dr_mode = "host";
        //snps,refclk_fladj;
        //snps,enable_guctl1_resume_quirk;
        //snps,enable_guctl1_ipd_quirk;
        //snps,xhci-stream-quirk;
        //dma-coherent;
    };

};

My dtb file:
&usb1 {
    status = "okay";
    xlnx,tz-nonsecure = <0x0>;
    xlnx,usb-polarity = <0x0>;
    xlnx,usb-reset-io = <0x1c>;
    xlnx,usb-reset-mode = <0x2>;
};

&dwc3_1 {
    /delete-property/ phy-names ;
    /delete-property/ phys ;
    //maximum-speed = "full-speed";
    snps,dis_u2_susphy_quirk ;
    snps,dis_u3_susphy_quirk ;
    status = "okay";
};

Enabled kernel options :
CONFIG_USB_ULPI_BUS
CONFIG_USB
CONFIG_USB_ANNOUNCE_NEW_DEVICES
CONFIG_USB_OTG
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_DBGCAP
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_PLATFORM
CONFIG_USB_STORAGE
CONFIG_USB_DWC3
CONFIG_USB_DWC3_ULPI
CONFIG_USB_DWC3_DUAL_ROLE
CONFIG_USB_DWC3_OF_SIMPLE
CONFIG_USB_DWC3_XILINX
CONFIG_USB_GADGET

Error log :
[   22.982212] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
[   23.195353] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[   23.203533] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   23.210668] usb 1-1: Product: Flash Disk
[   23.214589] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: USB
[   23.218331] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: SCY0000000016251
[   23.223791] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   23.230184] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 090c pid 1000: 400
[   23.236963] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[   24.703206] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB      Flash Disk       1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[   24.713527] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 15974400 512-byte logical blocks: (8.18 GB/7.62 GiB)
[   24.721903] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   24.726699] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[   24.732515] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   24.874292] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
[   25.682259] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
[   26.490258] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
[   27.294256] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
[   28.098271] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
[   28.902260] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
[   29.114969] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=4s
[   29.124536] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[   29.132105] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   29.141930] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read

The usb works with baremetal usb-ethernet gadget (my PCB is ok).
Any idea ?
Edit :
Usb ethernet device works great in high speed mode.
Edit 2:
With the mass storage debug option enabled in kernel :
[  261.232812] Bulk command transfer result=0
[  261.236900] xfer 4096 bytes, 1 entries
[  261.494344] Status code -71; transferred 0/4096
[  261.498874] -- unknown error
[  261.501745] Bulk data transfer result 0x4
[  261.505746] -- transport indicates error, resetting
[  261.636296] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci-hcd

The problems seems to only occur when the kernel tries to transfer a lot of data. 4096 bytes here for example...
